# How to check if an incoming email is duplicate in Inbox using javamail IMAP

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

Now I would like to check if an incoming email is duplicate via IMAP using javamail,
which may mean one email equals others that they have the same Subject,From,To,CC,BCC,Body,Attachements.But I donnot find any APIs to support this.

So can anybody tell me how to do this. any ideas are much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean literally duplicated emails, checking for two messages with the same Message-ID is probably the simplest.  If you just mean two emails that are "similar", you'll need to compare all the individual pieces yourself.  There are APIs to access all the parts of the email, but you'll have to write the comparison logic yourself.